# how to upload an image?

Tags: python, django, django-models

please help to fix the script.

in django1.6 I try to make the interface to load the image in sqllite.

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django import template
import datetime
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from proj1.forms.forms import ContactForm
from sends.models import Sends, Carousel, MediaForm


def admin_carousel(request):    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MediaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = MediaForm()
        t = template.loader.get_template('admin_carousel.html')
        c = template.Context({'name': 'Adrian'})
        html = t.render(c)      
        return HttpResponse(html, {'form': form})
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory

class Carousel(models.Model):
    media_file = models.FileField(upload_to='kalininCarousel/') 

MediaForm = modelform_factory(Carousel)
```

template.html:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="carousel_image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="img_car" value="" />

    <input type="submit" name="img_submit" value="Загрузить изображение" />
</form>
```

the problem is that after submitting the form I get the following error message:

```
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view proj1.views.views.admin_carousel didn't return an HttpResponse object.
Exception Location: C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response, line 132
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
def admin_carousel(request):    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MediaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

Django views **must** return a `HttpResponse` object, even if it's empty. Try something like this:

```
def admin_carousel(request):    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MediaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponse(200)
```